# Manipulating stars objects

Tags: r, r-stars

My question is about tranforming "stars" class objects.
As a result of a spacetime kriging, I have a stars object like the following:

```
stars object with 2 dimensions and 1 attribute
attribute(s):
               Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max.
var1.pred  11.64967 22.82501 25.30697 24.78288 26.75081 31.55394
dimension(s):
     from   to     offset  delta refsys point
sfc     1 1228         NA     NA     NA  TRUE
time    1    4 2020-06-01 8 days   Date    NA
                                                      values
sfc  POINT (745.5006 4847.393),...,POINT (579.0006 4995.893)
time                                                    NULL
```

Just to be more precise, what I would like to do is to "split" the sfc dimension into its "x" and "y" coordinates. I succeeded in doing this in a very involved way, consisting in
(1) building four dataframes (one for each time),
(2) making a "dimension" object by

```
st_dimensions(x = x, y = y, .raster = c("x", "y"))
```

(3) assembling 4 stars object into a list
(4) using code like

```
r = do.call("c", MMMlist) 
r = st_redimension(r)  
setNames(r,"var1.pred") -> r
r = st_set_dimensions(r, "new_dim", values = c(1,2,3,4), names = "time", point = TRUE)
```

for reassembling a stars object with three dimensions:

```
stars object with 3 dimensions and 1 attribute
attribute(s):
               Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. NA's
var1.pred  11.64967 22.82501 25.30697 24.78288 26.75081 31.55394 3792
dimension(s):
     from to  offset delta refsys point values x/y
x       1 64 516.001   4.5     NA FALSE   NULL [x]
y       1 34 4847.39   4.5     NA FALSE   NULL [y]
time    1  4       1     1     NA  TRUE   NULL
```

Which I can use with ggplot():

```
ggplot() + geom_stars(data = r) +
    coord_equal() +
    facet_wrap(~time) +
    theme_void() +
    scale_fill_steps(n.breaks=8,low="blue",high="orange") +
    #scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "magma",na.value="white") +
    scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,0))+
    scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0,0))
```

That's very involved and inelegant, and I am sure there is a more direct way to obtain two dimensions "x" and "y" from the sfc_POINT object that contains the (x,y) coordinates.

Thanks,
Roberto

Comment: Please, provide a reproducible example with your code so that we can best help you. If not possible, it would be nice to give us access to the `stars` object. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Unfortunately the code is rather long and requires a couple of data files. How can I give access to the stars object?

Comment: Perhaps you could export your 'stars' object as a `.tif` with `write_stars()`. And then share your file (zipped or not, depending on the size), via dropbox , google drive or any other platform by indicating the download link in your question.

Comment: Just to help someone with the same problem, eventually I solved my problem in the following way. I obtain the geometry by st_geometry(MMM), and coordinates by do.call(rbind, MMM.geom) %>% as_tibble() %>% setNames(c("x","y")). Then I convert MMM into an array by MMM %>% pull(1) -> MMM.arr and convert to dataframe MMM.df. Finally Ii reconstruct a convenient stars object by st_as_stars(MMM.df, dims=c("x","y"), and by merging the resulting attributes into one by merge().

Comment: Glad to see that you managed to solve your problem by yourself and thank  you very much for your feedback @Roberto Olmi